# How to use the variable multiple times in the Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I know about the basic principles of borrowing and owning in Rust.
However, I can't find a way to solve the following situation:

```
fn create_user(full_name: String) -> User {
  User {
    field1: full_name,
    field2: full_name,
  }
}
```

What if I would like to reference couple of fields in the example above to the given argument? Using of the "*" doesn't solve the problem and is not compiling.

I really did not find an answer to this question for a while before asking.

Comment: In this case you need to `.clone()` the string into the first field.

Comment: Should your 2 fields be strings or references to a string ?

Comment: tbh rust kinda sucks like that. I like python because it makes it so easy to pass around strings. but yeah, I’d second the clone appoach. I think it’s the only way here actually.

Comment: @IvanC and what if instead of the String, there will be a different object which doesn't support .clone()? And I also have read that it's not the best practice to use cloning all around cause it is not very efficiently from the point of view of performance.

Comment: @Peterrabbit , it should be String's

Comment: @StanislavStudzinskyi, if it doesn't implement clone, then you cannot use it more than once. You need to think about the properties of your types. If you are gonna need it more than once at a time (owned) you will need to clone it. Otherwise, you may have to use references or depending the case other solutions.

Comment: @Netwave thanks a lot, I kind of needed such confirmation.

Comment: I mean, whats wrong though with a cfg field like `#[allow_implicit_clone]`? I feel lik that would certainly save more developer time than posting a question on SO due to budding confusion about why it's necessary to `clone` something in a relatively simple scenario.

Comment: @rv.kvetch makes sense to me. I'm not an experienced Rust dev so I just want to make the most correct picture of how such a problem should be ideally solved.

Comment: @rv.kvetch That's because Python has a garbage collector. One of the defining features of Rust is its *lack* of garbage collection (along with its runtime overhead). (As I understand it, the memory used by any object has precisely one owner, and that memory can be freed as soon as the owner goes out of scope. The ownership system is all about maintaining that guarantee with no *runtime* overhead. It's a tradeoff between ease of writing code and runtime performance.)

Comment: can `field1` and `field2` have different values or is the idea that if you change `full_name` through `field1`, then `field2` is also automatically referring to the new value of `full_name`? If `field1` and `field2` are both owning their own separate version, then typing `.clone()` is making this explicit to the reader of your code.

Comment: @rv.kvetch: A newbie that will not discover `x.clone()` will have a harder time finding `#[allow_implicit_clone]`, unless it is applied to the `String` type in the `std` library. But then they will get confused when they can implicitly clone `String` but not their own types... Having to call `clone()` explicitly to clone an object is, IMHO, simpler and clearer than the alternatives.

Comment: Also note that [section 4.1 of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) covers this subject rather well, including explaining that values of type `String` are only moved on assignment, and how you can clone it in order to pass an equivalent string to multiple places.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options, including (and probably not only):

If `T` is `Clone`

```rust
fn create_user(full_name: T) -> User where T: Clone {
  User {
    field1: full_name.clone(),
    field2: full_name.clone(),
  }
}
```

if `T` is not `Clone`, you could leverage field2 as a method returning a reference:

```rust
struct User {
   field1: T
}

impl User {
    pub fn field2(&self) -> &T {
        &self.field1
    }
}

fn create_user(full_name: T) -> User {
  User {
    field1: full_name,
  }
}
```

Comment: nice; note that for a minor optimization also, I guess you could not `clone()` the second time.

Comment: I would guess that the question is more along the lines of *borrowing the same variable twice*. However, a string example is not ideal for this. For types other than strings, you only have two options in Rust, use `Rc` or go through the lifetimes-hell with references. Not to mention changing variables.